# Difficulties with installing test app on my ios device

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ipa

I am trying to install a version of my app on my device.
I have an ".ipa" file and a provisioning file that verified on my device.

When I am syncing my IOS device in Windows it says that I have a problem

```
"entitlements are not valid".
```

When pressing for more info it says I must update the device software,  and I don't want to do so.
How to fix it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about installing an application for testing, vs. doing this during development. If so, it is significantly, significantly less painful if you use a service like testflightapp.com instead of doing the iTunes dance.

Comment: i have a file that is not ipa it listed as xxx.app and this web does not reconize it

Comment: Here you go: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

Comment: i don't have xcode with my project on my windows and don't have access to mac in order to perform it.
made before this action from different computer but now it makes problems

Comment: The minimum iOS supported by the .ipa is the same or equal to that of your device, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have problem with that web because of data in entitlements.plist of my project.
the problem was with the certificate . i made the whole process of creating provisioning file and .ipa file .and changed it to distributing and not developer.
after that it works smoothly